# Proving $f$ is discontinuous at $x=c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f$ be a function that is defined on the real numbers, and let $c$ $\in$[$a,b$]. Assume $f(c)>0$, and suppose for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a point, $a_n$ $\in$ ($c$-$1\over n$, $c$ + $1\over n$) such that $f(a_n)$ $\leq$ 0. Prove $f$ is not continuous at $x=c$.

I am having trouble with this proof, but I have some ideas. My attempt:

Assume to the contrary that $f$ is continuous at $c$. By the sequential definition of continuity, $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(c)$. By a similar theorem proven previously, since $a_n$ $\in$ ($c$-$1\over n$, $c$ + $1\over n$), we know ($a_n$) converges to $c$. Thus, taking $\epsilon>0,$ |$a_n$-$c$| $< \epsilon.$

However, using the delta-epsilon definition, if $f$ is continuous at $c$ then for every $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists a $\delta$ such that|$f(a_n)-f(c)$|$< \epsilon$ for all $a_n$ such that |$a_n$-$c$|$<\delta.$

So I am not sure which definition would be better to use in this situation.

I think I need to pick a certain value if epsilon to show that my assumption ($f$ is continuous at $c$) is false, but I do not know how to find it. I'm also confused as to whether or not I should use the sequential definition of continuity or the delta-epsilon definition, or if it even matters.

Hopefully I am on the right track, but any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, and that is referring to the definition.

Whichever definition you use, you will be fine.

It is clear from your description that $a_n \to c$. Suppose $f$ were continuous by sequential criteria. If $f(a_n) \leq 0$ for all $n$, then $f(a_n) \to f(c)$ is true, however this implies $f(c) \leq 0$, contrary to our knowledge that $f(c) > 0$. Hence discontinuity follows.

If $f(c) > 0$, I urge you to attempt contradicting the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition with taking $\epsilon = \frac{f(c)}{2} > 0$, and showing that there is no $\delta$ at all. I'll hide the answer in the yellow box below:

> Suppose there is a $\delta >0$ such that the continuity definition holds. Take $n$ large enough so that $\frac 1n < \delta$. Then, there is $a_n \in (c-\frac 1n, c + \frac 1n)$ such that $|f(a_n) - f(c)| > \epsilon$, this contradicts the nature of the chosen $\delta$.